# How to let git pull from branch not from tag?

Tags: git, git-pull

Our repo happens to have a tag that has the same name as the branch name. So when I try to pull from that branch, git confused and pulled from tag, like this. I have to delete that tag first to make my git pull work.

So how do I tell git pull from branch not from tag ?

```
cc-backend ➤ git pull origin 0.9.0-rc6-patch1                                       
From 10.0.0.28:webcc/cc-backend
 * tag                 0.9.0-rc6-patch1 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

/* I have to delete that tag and git pull again to get the result I want */

cc-backend ➤ git pull origin 0.9.0-rc6-patch1                                       
From 10.0.0.28:webcc/cc-backend
 * branch              0.9.0-rc6-patch1 -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 9d7e9dc3..2bf3f96a
Fast-forward
 app/Services/GroupSeat/Seat.php | 5 ++---
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems the remote repository has a tag and a branch with the same name `0.9.0-rc6-patch1`. Use the full name to fetch/pull,

```
# fetch/pull the tag
git fetch/pull origin refs/tags/0.9.0-rc6-patch1

# fetch/pull the branch
git fetch/pull origin refs/heads/0.9.0-rc6-patch1
```

Comment: See all the refs with [`git show-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref)

Comment: @BradTurek In this case, we need to inspect the refs in the *remote* repository. We can use `git ls-remote`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the full name like

`git checkout refs/heads/<branchname>`

or for tag

`git checkout refs/tags/<refname>`

For pull 
`git pull origin refs/heads/<branchname>`

To access the relevant documentation type in 
`git help revisions`

Refer the `SPECIFYING REVISIONS` section

Comment: To pull instead of check out, `git pull origin refs/heads/<branchname>`

Answer (score 1):

By default, a fetch refspec is `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

So you can also `git fetch` (which fetches all the branches), then merge or rebase your branch with `origin/<remote branch>`

But a more convenient workaround would be to agree on a naming convention for tags: `v0.9.0-rc6-patch1` instead of `0.9.0-rc6-patch1`. That way, no more mix-up.